# How to disable zoom in plotly choropleth mapbox plot with Python?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, mapbox, choropleth

Here is my code:

```
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(district_df[['District','Confirmed','Deaths','id','province']], geojson = geo_df, locations='id', color='Confirmed',
                           color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
                           mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                           zoom=5.9, hover_name = 'District',hover_data = {'District':False, 'Confirmed':True,'Deaths':True,'province':False,'id':False},
                           opacity=0.5, center = {"lat": 28.3949, "lon": 84.1240})
```

I would like to disable the zooming option. Is there a way?

Comment: You can disable it by not specifying `zoom=5.9,` but do you intend to do anything else?

Comment: @r-beginners thanks for your input. What I meant was to disable the scrolling and zooming of the map that comes default with Plotly. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: I think the purpose of the zoom feature in maps is to optimize it for the user. If you want to disable it, why not get involved in the root of choosing PLOTLY?

Comment: I get what you mean. I am building a Streamlit web application and I will like the map to be interactive (which is why I choose Plotly) but my web application would look better and easy to view if I disable the scroll-zoom feature while keeping the interactivity alive. I hope this makes it clear what I am trying to achieve. I found there are ways to disable it in it JS but I couldn't find anything on Python.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, update_layout will do if you set dragmode=False.

https://community.plotly.com/t/map-graph-disable-scrollzoom-drag/9664